# AdMob accounts().list()

Tags: api, admob

Good day for everyone.
I am trying to work with AdMob reporting API.

I want to get my publisher_id.

I found next topic: https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/reference/rest/v1/accounts/list

And, if I am using the UI way ("Execute") to get it, then I am receiving response body with publisher_id inside.

Otherwise, if I am using the AdMob API: https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/getting-started

method: authenticate().accounts().list()

I cannot get this information, and I receive empty body.

But, I can still get any other info. Can somebody tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution. You need to add to method .execute() and the you will receive the correct object.

Instead of authenticate().accounts().list(), use authenticate().accounts().list().execute()

Comment: please share your complete code @1rone